# How can I see the available tokens for message templates?

Tags: templates, smarty, message-templates

For a page in the browser, we can put &smartyDebug=1 in the URL to see variables in scope for the top level template. How can we do this for message templates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use **{debug output=html}**

To have a nice formatting in html email

Answer (score 7):

Insert **{debug}** into a message template then perform the relevant action (ie make an online contribution if you modified **Contributions - Receipt (on-line)**). The email sent will contain a list of all the smarty variables assigned to that template

Comment: A limitation of this approach is that it doesn't work for all templates.  For instance, in 4.6.2 I can make this work on emails sent from a Contact screen, for a Contribution email ... but NOT for an activity reminder email.  In fact, I'm not even sure Smarty is active for the reminder emails?

Comment: When I inserted {debug} in the message template, the debug information was showing only in the headers of the email (viewable only when you click "View Source" or equivalent). So I copied that debug information from there, pasted it into Notepad++ and saved it as an HTML file. I had to remove the javascript surrounding the html. I also replaced all instances of `\/` with `/`. Now when I loaded the HTML file in my browser, I had a READABLE debug information, showing me all the smarty variables available to me.

Comment: Also, I was modifying the **Contributions - Receipt (on-line)** message template but I didn't want to go through submitting the whole donation form just to check whether my changes looked good. So I went to **Find Contributions**, then selected one of the contributions I had already made and from the Actions dropdown at the top, I chose **Print or Email Contribution Receipt**. This way I could quickly make small changes to the template and see if I achieved what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

You can insert the `{debug}` Smarty token into your template: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,14845.msg63471.html#msg63471