# $formValues field names

Tags: contributions, system-workflow-messages

Editing the work flow messages, I'm looking for the field names preceded by $formValues.
More specific I would like to include a line displaying the origin of the contribution in the work flow message *"Contributions - Receipt (off-line)"*.
Where to find all the field names that can be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see the available tokens for message templates?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-can-i-see-the-available-tokens-for-message-templates)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing on what form you are exactly, there is bound to be something like contributionId or contributionID in your form.

You can find the name in the $form object (try debugging the object for the specific name) and then use `$contributionId = $form->getVar('_contributionID')` to get the field and use it in your hook (assuming you are using a hook).

Comment: This isn't a form but a system workflow message, so there's only Smarty available here.

Comment: Okay, I was thrown in the wrong direction by the $formValues.